# jenkins build not getting trigger for github push

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Currently trying to automate the job build process to every github push. I have did the following steps to automate still it's not getting automated. what I am missing I did not get.

1. installed Github Integration plugin
2. in github for this repository integration added the service webhook url as  http://{IP Address}:{PORT}/github-webhook
3. in Jenkins server created ssh key for the user jenkins and added that into this repository deploy keys.
4. to check the ssh connection ran the command - ssh git@github.com. it successful.
5. in jenkins setup [image]
6. Build Trigger [image]
7. after the push in github services it showing it was successful but in jenkins not triggered.

What am I missing?

Comment: What error are you facing? @Pranavadurai

Comment: @TanviGarg after git push.automated build not getting submit.

Comment: Its mentioned that Integration services in Github would be replaced in the near future by Webhooks. It's really easy to integrate webhooks and basically does the same push notification option as well. Might as well try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running "Test Hook"? Did it come back with a response?

There is a check box near the bottom of the authentication section labeled “Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits” that needs to be unchecked in order for this particular method to work.

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: Where we can uncheck this option ?

Comment: It is in jenkins. Also It will be really helpful if you can try running Test hook from Git. Its response will throw more light on whats going wrong with your setup.

Comment: unable to find this setting in jenkin's could you specify where i an find this. i am using pipeline project.

Answer (score 2):

Firs of all You Need to setup **github with jenkins** in below section also

Go to [Github](https://github.com/) --> **click on profile dropdown** --> **settings** --> **devloper settings** --> **personal access token** --> **generate new token** --> **select all scopes** --> **copy the token**

Then go to [Jenkins](http://localhost:8080) --> **manage Jenkins** --> **github settings** --> **add user** --> **Select secret text**--> **paste the token**

> ***Then Test the git-hub connection by clicking test button If its Successful the Jenkins will trigger whenever you commit to git-hub***

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all of these things are done correctly for me it was just .git missing at the end of repository url

1. use https://github.com/user/repo.git instead of https://github.com/user/repo in Repository URL field
2. make sure if you are using reverse-proxy headers check if the values are correct for proxy
3. make sure jenkins -> configure global security -> csrf protection -> check the box for proxy compatibility

Comment: Have wasted so many hours till I found this! thanks !